# Query with COUNT() and GROUP BY

Tags: sql

**DATA**

```
ID-USER-ROLE-PERM
1   1   1   1
2   1   1   2
3   1   1   3
4   1   1   4
5   1   1   5
6   1   1   6
12  1   1   7
13  1   1   8
9   1   3   1
10  1   3   5
11  1   4   1
14  13  1   8
```

**Query description:** How many users take value 1 as `ROLE`?

**Result should be:** 2

because only user number 1 and 13 takes value 1 as `ROLE`

This is my faulty query which returns 9:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assigned_roles WHERE ROLE = 1 GROUP BY ROLE
```

Any idea how to return 2 instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To count the number of different users use `COUNT(DISTINCT USER)`.

Also you don't need `GROUP BY ROLE` as your `WHERE` clause ensures that there can only be a maximum of one group.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USER) 
FROM assigned_roles 
WHERE ROLE = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f977c/2)

Comment: It might not be obvious, please explain.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. I just needed to implement into my big query.